# Using `duplicated` function to identify duplicated rows in a `data.table` with key

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to determine the rows in a `data.table` that are duplicated. Here's the sample code I used.

```
a<-c(1,2,3,3,5)
b<-c(6,7,8,9,10)
require(data.table)
DT<-data.table(a,b)
setkey(DT,a)
DT
#   a  b
# 1: 1  6
# 2: 2  7
# 3: 3  8
# 4: 3  9
# 5: 5 10
setkey(DT,a)
duplicated(DT)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

As you can see, I am identifying row 4 as a duplicated row, which is incorrect as DT[3:4,"b",with=FALSE] is different. Am I using the `duplicated` function wrong?

Comment: Have a look at `?duplicated.data.table` as well.

Comment: @Arun I checked it, but got confused at the definition for argument `by` which states: "A NULL or FALSE value uses all columns and acts like the analogous data.frame methods."

Comment: Yes, what confused you about that? Especially when the line before that states, "Defaults to `key(x)` which, by default, only uses *key* columns".

Comment: I thought if the default value of `by` was changed from `key(x)` to `NULL` or `FALSE`, `duplicated` would have considered all columns instead of the key.

Comment: Yes, that's right. `duplicated(DT, by=NULL)` gives the result you expect, isn't it? If you don't provide anything for `by`, by default, it'll take the value for `by` as `key(DT)`.. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Yes, NULL works. However, setting by to `FALSE` does not (bug?), perhaps I used that earlier.

Comment: Aha, that's correct! Just checked as well. Will fix that. Must've been a regression from 1.8.10. Thank you.

Comment: filed [bug #5424](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=975&aid=5424&group_id=240) and fixed. `by=TRUE/FALSE` both will result in error. Use `by=NULL`. `?duplicated.data.table` is also updated. Will be good to go in 1.9.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`duplicated.datatable` has a `by` argument which defaults to the key columns

Therefore if you set this to consider all columns, it will perform as you wish

```
duplicated(DT, by = names(DT))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```